# bulk GET using HATEOAS

Tags: rest, api, bulk, hateoas

I've seen many examples of HATEOAS where every resource has links to related resources. An API that returns N items of a certain resource per page, the client would probably need N calls to fetch any nested resource by consuming HATEOAS. For example:

**GET city/documents:**

```
[{
    id: 1,
    city: {
        self: 'http://service.com/cities?filter=id==1'
    },
    document: { ... }
    ...

}, {
    id: 2,
    city: {
        self: 'http://service.com/cities?filter=id==2'
    },
    document: { ... }
    ...
}]
```

FYI, the query parameter uses the FIQL syntax to define the filters.

Now, if the client was to fetch the city details for each document (to show on UI), it will probably need N additional calls. However in my case, the `/cities` API can additionally take multiple city ids like this: `/cities?filter=id=in=(1,2)` that can reduce N calls to one. Is there a way to articulate something like this using HATEOAS? I've read about the templates but not sure how should the template look like and how would client consume it?

Answer (score 0):

> I've seen many examples of HATEOAS where every resource has links to related resources. An API that returns N items of a certain resource per page, the client would probably need N calls to fetch any nested resource by consuming HATEOAS.

Yes.  Less true in a world with Server-Push, where the server can proactively provide multiple resources in response to a query.  If you imagine asking for a web page, and getting the html, and then also the images and the java script resources *too*, then you've got the right sort of idea.

> API can additionally take multiple city ids like this: /cities?filter=id=in=(1,2) that can reduce N calls to one. Is there a way to articulate something like this using HATEOAS?

Yes.

Let's walk through it carefully.  What you've done here is introduced a new resource, with identifier `/cities?filter=id=in=(1,2)`.  You might have another resource `/cities?filter=id=in=(1,20)` and another resource `/cities?filter=id=in=(1,2000)`.  In your *implementation*, these might be a "single endpoint" that extracts parameters from the identifier and uses them to generate the correct representation.

So what you get is something like a data transfer object - a large grained resource fetched in a single go.

> I've read about the templates but not sure how should the template look like and how would client consume it?

The simplest example, which you have likely seen already, is a web form.  You allow the client to provide the start and end elements, and the form processing takes that information and creates the specified URI from it.

```
/filtered-cities?start=1&end=2000
```

So the client needs to understand what the form is for, and how to identify the semantics of the different elements in the form.  The *agent* needs to understand the processing rules that transfer the form data into the URI.

[URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) are the same basic idea; they give you a domain agnostic language with which to describe where the parameters go in a resource identifier.  The basic pattern is the same - there needs to be agreement about the semantics of the parameters, the server provides a URI, the client provides a parameter map, and the generic code can take care of the merge

```
uri = template.apply(parameterMap)
```

URI Templates aren't quite as powerful as forms; with a form, you can introduce a default value for a parameter, but there is no analogous capability in URI templates.

[HAL-Forms](https://rwcbook.github.io/hal-forms/) may give you a better sense of how a form based approach might work in JSON.